# Can I pull out URL parameters from different format than normally used on react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're about to relaunch an existing website, that was previously a wordpress site and now is going to be a react site.
The routing is done via react-router-dom and there are a couple of pages which will render dynamically depending on the parameters in the url.

There is one page that is basically used for a user to put in their data and sign up. This component has two parameters, one which is the user-id and another one.
The link to that component gets sent out to people who have previously expressed interest through the website and then gets mailed to them. This component also existed on the wordpress site, but lived on a very different route.
So now when we relaunch we want to make sure people with the old link still get redirected to the new, correct component instead of getting a 404.

My question is now, is there a way for me to redirect from the old url (which also contains both parameters in the slug) to the new one while passing on the parameters?
The old url looked like this:
`.com/confirmation-FIRST_PARAM/?IDref=:SECOND_PARAM`
The new url for rendering this page looks like this:
`.com/confirmation/:FIRST_PARAM/:SECOND_PARAM`
My first naive approach was to just create a new route in my `App.js` file like so:

```
<Route
 path="/confirmation-:firstParam/?IDref=:id"
 component={Confirmation}
 />
```

which doesn't work. I guess that's because it's not really complying with how parameters are passed in react-router. Is there a way to redirect users to the appropriate new page?

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to get it to work, but I don't think it's the smartest way possible (or at least it feels like there should be a leaner solution).

I added another route for the old links and then within the component I am using the `useLocation()` hook to figure out at which pathname the component actually gets rendered.
Depending on that I set the first parameter. The user id is then extracted by using the search property of the location object:
`oldId = location.search.split("=")[1];`

Using the old id, the other param (pkf) and the `useHistory` hook I then redirect to the new route:

```
history.push(`/confirmation/${oldId}/${oldPkf}`);
```

Whenever now a user accesses the component through an old link, the parameters get pulled from the location and the user gets redirected to the new link.